# Writing two regex patterns inside another

Tags: regex

I have some strings that can be written in two different ways. I am trying to extract both patterns in the same piece of regex.

The first i'm hoping to do is extract the substring before a substring (i'll call this "endWord")

So

```
Title Text (Descriptor Text) endword - More words i don't want
```

Would turn into `"Title Text (Descriptor Text)"`

NEXT, of this substring i just extract, i am hoping to extract just the word before the `" ("` (if it exists)

So the final result will be `"Title Text"`.

`(.+?(?= endWord))(.+?(?= \())` ends in no result

Comment: Does `(.*)(?=\s\(.*\)\sendword)` work ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W9rYpp/1))?

Comment: @JacobLee I don't think you would need the inner lookahead

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(.*?)\s+\([^()]*\)(?=\s+endword\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5ztje/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\([^()]*\)` - `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`, and then `)`
- `(?=\s+endword\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more whitespaces and a whole word `endword` immediately to the right of the current location.